# Sharepoint 2013 - design manager vs custom VS solution

Tags: master-page, design, branding, manager

I would like to know what the benefits/disadvantages are for using the design manager to brand a publishing site?
I come from the SP 2010 world where a site collection scoped feature would be developed to apply the masterpage/pagelayout and css changes.

Questions i am not too sure about:

1. if i need to make a change after the package has been deployed to 100 site collections, what is the process?
2. is the branding automatically applied to a sub site? (as when i tried with a team site it would only apply the branding when the publishing feature was activated on the web)

Appreciate some guidance on this one!